# Eclipse Indigo not running project after installing Lombok

Tags: java, eclipse-indigo, lombok

I've recently installed Lombok (version 0.11.0) into my Eclipse Indigo installation and now all of my projects in Eclipse no longer launch, both from Run and Debug.

The error I am getting is the following when I try and run a project

```
Usage: javaw [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
or  javaw [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
-client   to select the "client" VM
-server   to select the "server" VM
-hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
              The default VM is client.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose[:class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -jre-no-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
```

This suggests to me that it cannot find the main class file for the project I am running but it correctly references the project in the run and debug configuration, the file is there in the project and I've checked the /bin folder to make sure the class is in there (which it is).

The only thing I can think of which may or may not be causing a problem is that just after the Lombok installation, the /bin folder did not contain the correct contents, instead it built my JUnit test cases in there.

I've already cleaned my entire project set several times and uninstalled/re-installed Lombok. I've reset my computer and still no joy. Eclipse is running with jdk 1.6.30.

**UPDATE:** The problem seems to lie in if the project references another project using Lombok or that project uses Lombok directly. Removing the references to Lombok to the project allows the project to execute normally in Eclipse.

Comment: It looks like java gets wrong arguments rather than a missing argument or non-existing main class. And that's strange as it's nothing lombok works with; it's only needed during compile.

Comment: Hmm, OK. I'll check the arguments Eclipse is using to launch with.